# Will changing a list name affect lookup columns?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, lookup-column

Will changing a list or library name affect other lists that use it as a reference/lookup column? Or will they automatically be pointed to the updated name?

I am working on renaming a couple lists and libraries but I am worried that I will lose all my lookup data if I decide to rename to source lists/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

Changing list name will not affect any lists using lookup from this list. It will be automatically handled by SharePoint.

Comment: If you have any custom solutions using REST api and referencing lists with `getByTitle()` endpoint then you need to change it with new display name of lists.

Comment: Hi @plouie21, Does this answer your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with same problem in future. If you have any doubt please ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Connections on lookup columns will not be affected.

The list name under “Get information from:” will be automatically updated to the new list name, no data would be lost.